# Characteristic exponent Levy process

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, stochastic-processes

The Levy-Khintchine formula tells us what the characteristic function of a Levy process looks like. Given a process $Y_t$, the characteristic function of $Y_1$ is given by
\begin{equation}
 \phi_1(u) = e^{\Psi(u)},
\end{equation}
where
\begin{equation}
 \Psi(u) =i \mu u - \frac{1}{2}\sigma^2 u^2 +\int_{\mathbb{R}} \left(e^{i u x} -1 - 
  i  u  x \mathbf{1}_{(-1,1)} \right) \nu(\mathtt{d} x ).
\end{equation}
Is $e^{-\Psi(u)}$ *also* the characteristic function of a Levy process? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't know much about this stuff (Levy processes, etc) but wouldn't the minus sign ruin the boundedness of $\exp(\Psi(u))$?

Comment: No, $\Psi$ is complex valued: $\Psi: \mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{C}$.And $|\phi_1(u)|\leq 1$ for all $u$ (characteristic function of a probability measure).

Comment: Take the Wiener process; $-\Psi(u) = \frac 1 2 \sigma^2 u^2$ so $\exp(-\Psi(u))$ is unbounded for real valued $u$.

Answer (score 2):

**HINT**: Consider simple examples of Levy processes: Wiener process, Poisson process and check if $\exp\left(-\Psi(u)\right)$ is a characteristic function of a random variable. (see [criteria](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Characteristic_function_%28probability_theory%29#Criteria_for_characteristic_functions), and use examples: [first](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Characteristic_function_%28probability_theory%29#Criteria_for_characteristic_functions), [second](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/76376/11069), [third](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/178905/combinations-of-characteristic-functions-alpha-phi-11-alpha-phi-2), [fourth](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/65343/showing-cost2-is-not-a-characteristic-function))

For Wiener process, $\Psi(u) = -\frac{1}{2} \sigma^2 u^2$, for Poisson process $\Psi(u) = \lambda \left(\mathrm{e}^{i u x} - 1 \right)$.