# characteristic function of stable symmetric distribution

Tags: probability-theory

I'm stuck with one problem of my homework:

"Show that $\phi\left(t\right) = {\rm e}^{−\left\vert\,t\,\right\vert^{\,\alpha}}\,, t \in {\mathbb R}$, is a characteristic function only for $0 \leq \alpha \leq 2$".

I'm trying with Polya's criterion but I cannot use it since the second derivative depends on t and it shouldn't
$\left(~\mbox{it should be bigger than zero on}\ {\mathbb R}_{+}~\right)$.
So, i tried with Bochner’s theorem, and again I cannot understand why it should be positive definite only for 0 ≤ α ≤ 2.

Could someone give me an idea on how to solve this problem?

Infinitely thanks

Comment: look at this http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/76369/for-symmetric-stable-distributions-why-is-alpha-le-2